# Runtime error when run the application, and the reason is the Qlable

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel

The problem is when run the application, appears a message to close the application without clarifying the cause of the problem.

the application is a simple calculator in order to addition two numbers.
This application contains six GUI objects.
Two `QSpinBox` to input the numbers.
Three `Qlabel`, two `Qlabel` to display `+`, `=` ,and one other to output the result of addition of two number, `and this object is the reason of the problem`.
Finally, one `QPushButton` to display the result in a `Qlabel`.

**Now, It's time to display code:**
I have three files(`main.cpp`, `calculator.h`, `calculator.cpp`).

**-- Main.cpp --**

```
#include "calculat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   Calculator calc;
   calc.show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

**-- calculator.h --**

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_H
#define CALCULATOR_H

#include <QWidget>

class QSpinBox;
class QLabel;

class Calculator : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Calculator();

private slots:
   void on_addNumber_clicked();

public:
   QSpinBox *firstValueSpinBox;
   QSpinBox *secondValueSpinBox;
   QLabel *resultLabel;
};

#endif // CALCULATOR_H
```

**-- calculator.cpp --**

```
#include "calculator.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

Calculator::Calculator(){
   QPushButton *addButton = new QPushButton("Add");
   firstValueSpinBox = new QSpinBox();
   secondValueSpinBox = new QSpinBox();
   resultLabel = new QLabel();
   QLabel *addLabel = new QLabel("+");
   QLabel *equalLabel = new QLabel("=");

   connect(addButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_addNumber_clicked()));

   QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
   layout->addWidget(firstValueSpinBox);
   layout->addWidget(addLabel);
   layout->addWidget(secondValueSpinBox);
   layout->addWidget(addButton);
   layout->addWidget(equalLabel);
   layout->addWidget(resultLabel);
}

void Calculator::on_addNumber_clicked(){
   int num = this->firstValueSpinBox->value();
   int num2 = this->secondValueSpinBox->value();
   QString outResult = QString::number(num + num2);
   resultLabel->setText(outResult);       //<< the problem here
}
```

I doubt in this line:

```
resultLabel->setText(outResult);
```

When remove that previous line, the application work fine.
Conclusion, the problem in this `Qlabel` object that responsible for display the final result.

```
QLabel *resultLabel; // declaration in calculator.h

resultLabel->setText(outResult); // in calculator.cpp
```

Comment: Firstly, you probably want `resultLabel->setText(outResult);` (without the quotes around `outResult`).  Secondly, I don't get any errors when I run the program you've written.  What is the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: +1 for code that actually compiles and runs. Next time, when posting a test case, please put it all in one file (`main.cpp`) and put `#include "main.moc"` at the end. That's the "no header" idiom in Qt.

Comment: @RA: For the `(without the quotes around outResult).` because for writing codes quickly. but this error not the primary reason of error. Secondly I have no error when compiling the code, the problem in runtime mode(displays a close window only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no crashing bugs in your code. It runs just fine. Your problem is a rather classical result of stale object files that don't match the code anymore. The code generated from `moc_calculator.cpp` is stale. How are you building the project: manually, or using make/qmake? If you use make/qmake or make/cmake (say, from Qt Creator), do the following:

1. Completely remove the build directory (you'll find it one directory above the sources).
2. Rebuild.

There's a functional bug that doesn't result in a crash, simply in a misbehavior. Maybe it's even a typo. Instead of `resultLabel->setText("outResult");`, you want

```
resultLabel->setText(outResult);
```

Comment: Relation to `resultLabel->setText("outResult")`;. because for writing codes quickly. but this error not the primary reason of error.